# Adding an img element to a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to add an img to the `placehere` div using JavaScript, however I am having no luck. Can anyone give me a hand with my code?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("src", "images/hydrangeas.jpg");
elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild("elem");
</script>
<body>

<div id="placehere">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
```

not

```
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild("elem");
```

and use the below to set the source

```
elem.src = 'images/hydrangeas.jpg';
```

Comment: OK, I took the var out of quotes but I still don't see an image

Comment: @AndrewDeForest: `appendChild` expects an object and then it should work unless the path to your image is wrong. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/S57rs/

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea. I changed it to elem.src = "images/hydrangeas.jpg" and I still don't see it. I even wrote out the tag <img src="images/hydrangeas.jpg"> just to make sure the path was correct, and it showed up.

Comment: Are you sure that the script runs?

Comment: I think my script was running before the DOM finished loading, so I added document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() and it seemed to fix it!

Answer (score 33):

It should be:

```js
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
```

And place your `div` before your *javascript*, because if you don't, the *javascript* executes before the `div` exists. Or wait for it to load. So your code looks like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
  elem.setAttribute("src", "http://img.zohostatic.com/discussions/v1/images/defaultPhoto.png");
  elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
  elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
  elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
  document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<div id="placehere"></div>
```

To prove my point, see this [with the onload](https://jsfiddle.net/LrEEb/) and this [without the onload](https://jsfiddle.net/4wFsy/). Fire up the console and you'll find an error stating that the `div` doesn't exist or cannot find `appendChild` method of `null`.

Comment: Forget all the *setAttribute* calls, just set the properties directly: `elem.src = ...; elem.height = ...; elem.alt = ...;` and so on.

Comment: Agreed, but as far as I know, using this method has no drawbacks. Maybe we should set up a performance test on JSPerf

Comment: [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/setattribute-vs-set-using-property) shows that setAttribute is actually faster. Nice.

Comment: The difference in performance is negligible, but for the record, [here's one](http://jsperf.com/setattribute-or-property) that goes the other way in some browsers. More to the point is the inconsistency of *setAttribute* across browsers versus the consistency of setting properties. In HTML5 compliant browsers the two do the same thing, so it is hardly surprising that performance in such browsers is nearly identical.

Comment: Perhaps it's faster if you aren't appending it. That's what I deduce from that test. You're right about consistency, of course.

Comment: *setAttribute* is a host method and has a specified outcome but nothing else, same with accessing properties of host objects. That is very different to calling an ECMAScript native function vs object property access (where the function call should always be slower). It may well be in the host case that setting a property is doing exactly what *setAttribute* does (or vice versa) so whether one is faster than the other is just luck. It's also difficult to isolate the two operations to make them indenpendant of other processing.

Answer (score 5):

```
function image()
{
    //dynamically add an image and set its attribute
    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src="p1.jpg"
    img.id="picture"
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    foo.appendChild(img);
}

<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution seems to be a much shorter version for that:

```
<div id="imageDiv"></div>
```

In Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img width="100" height="100" src="images/hydrangeas.jpg">';
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to do it with JQuery:

```js
$("<img height='200' width='200' alt='testImage' src='https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/47340995?v=4'> </img>").appendTo("#container");
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2