# How to add element inside the div

Tags: javascript

Let I've created an element as the following:

```
var elem= document.createElement("p");
```

And I've a `div#parent` element. How can I put elem inside the `div#parent`? Is it possible to do without `jQuery`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an img element to a div with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use appendChild method to add / append a child.

```
document.getElementById('parent').appendChild( document.createElement("p") );
```

**More Info:**

[appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, have to use jQuery. That's your only option. :)

Just kidding.

Something like this should work:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

It's that simple. Even without using good 'ole jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use **[`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)**:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var elem= document.createElement("p");
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can!

```
var parent = document.querySelector("div#parent");
//or document.getElementById("parent");
//I doubt speed is an issue so both will work the same
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

By `appendChild()`

```
var elem = document.createElement("p");
var div  = document.getElementById("parent");
div.appendChild(elem);
```

And to alaborate. jQuery is written in pure Javascript. Anything jQuery do, you can do. That said, there are various quirks etc. that it abstract away.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.appendChild(elem);
```