# passing php value to on click (getFunction(this.value)) problems

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to receive data from MYSQL, to use for voting poll 
for 2 specific columns, I am storing it in a table, I then added radio button, like yes or no , but because of multiples radio button(displayed for each row of the specified column), I have to have unique identifier and after vote I need to know where the user has clicked to update the database.

```
                echo '<td><div id="H'.$ingID.'"></div><form id ="H1'.$ingID.'"> Yes: <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_yes '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id="halal_yes" onclick="getVote(this.value)">';
                echo '<br>No: <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_no '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id="halal_no" onclick="getVote(this.value)"> </form></td>';
                echo '<td>'.($row["vegi?"]).'</td></tr>';
            }else if (is_null($row["vegi?"]) && !is_null($row["halal?"])){
                echo '<td>'.($row["halal?"]).'</td>';
                echo '<td><div id="V'.$ingID.'"></div><form id ="V1'.$ingID.'"> Yes: <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_yes '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id="vegi_yes" onclick="getVote(this.value)">';
                echo '<br>No: <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_no '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id="vegi_no" onclick="getVote(this.value)"> </form></td></tr>';
            }else {
                echo  '<td><div id="H'.$ingID.'"></div><form id ="H1'.$ingID.'"> Yes: <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_yes '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" onclick="getVote(this.value)">';
                echo '<br>No: <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_no '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id="halal_no" onclick="getVote(this.value)"> </form></td>';
                echo '<td><div id="V'.$ingID.'"></diV><form id ="V1'.$ingID.'"> Yes: <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_yes '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" onclick="getVote(this.value)">';
                echo '<br>No: <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_no '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" id=vegi_no onclick="getVote(this.value)"> </form></td></tr>';
```

i think because i am passing php variable its passing as an object and giving me error

ultimate want I want to achieve is something like this even though is not working, though the value is being passed as checked by alert(item) and 
alert(testsplit[0])

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
        function getVote(item) {

            var testsplit = item.split(" ");
            var hingID= "";
            var vingID = "";
            var voteyes = "";
            var voteno = "";
            var no=true;

            if (testsplit[0]=="halal_yes") {
                 hingID= testsplit[1];
                 voteyes = 1 + testsplit[2];
                 voteno = testsplit[3];
                 no = false;
            }else if (testsplit[0]=="halal_no"){
                 hingID= testsplit[1];
                 voteyes = testsplit[2];
                 voteno = 1 + testsplit[3];
            }else if(testsplit[0]=="vegi_yes"){
                 vingID= testsplit[1];
                 voteyes = 1 + testsplit[2];
                 voteno = testsplit[3];
                 no = false;
            }else if(testsplit[0]== "vegi_no"){
                 vingID= testsplit[1];
                 voteyes = 1 + testsplit[2];
                 voteno = testsplit[3];
            }
            alert(testsplit);

            if(!hingID && no==true){
                document.getElementById("V1"+vingID).remove();
                var wsize=100*Math.round(voteno/(voteno+voteyes);
                var ihtml = "<img src="img/poll.gif" width ="+wsize+height="20">+wsize+"%"";
                document.getElementById("V"+vingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
            }else if (!hingID && no == false){
                document.getElementById("V1"+vingID).remove();
                var wsize=100*Math.round(voteyes/(voteno+voteyes);
                var ihtml = "<img src="img/poll.gif" width ="+wsize+height="20">+wsize+"%"";
                document.getElementById("V"+vingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
            }else if (!vingID && no==true){
                document.getElementById("H1"+hingID).remove();
                var wsize=100*Math.round(vote/(voteno+voteyes);
                var ihtml = "<img src="img/poll.gif" width ="+wsize+height="20">+wsize+"%"";
                document.getElementById("H"+hingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
            }else if (!vingID && no==false){
                document.getElementById("H1"+ingID).remove();
                var wsize=100*Math.round(voteyes/(voteno+voteyes);
                var ihtml = "<img src="img/poll.gif" width ="+wsize+height="20">+wsize+"%"";
                document.getElementById("H"+hingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
            }    
}
</script>
```

i am not good with javascript and prefer php, therefore i also tried passing value to another php file but it didn't work , any suggestions how I can make this workable.

After debugging I realised that the array is passed however it is not giving the right value any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) - When sending an set of data (PHP) use this function to convert it into a JSON Object 
 Go through the above link as it will make your life much easier once you get the hang of it..

try simplifying your code.. for getting the radio buttons use a function like below where you add the checked values into an array on submit

```
 <div id="H-id"><h1>Halal Poll</h1></div>
<form id="H1-id">
    <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_yes " id="halal_yes"><label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="halal" value="halal_no" id="halal_no"><label>No</label>
</form>

<div id="V-id"><h1>Vegi Poll</h1></div>
<form id="V1-id">
    <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_yes" id="vegi_yes"><label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="vegi" value="vegi_no" id="vegi_no"><label>No</label>
</form>
<button id="getValues">getValues</button>

  // On submit
  $("#getValues").click(function(){
          var Halal_Answer  = document.getElementsByName('halal'); // Halal Radios
          var Vegi_Answer  = document.getElementsByName('vegi'); // Vegi Radios
          var Answers = {};

      //    Loop through the set of radios
          var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
          var Answers = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
              if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
                  // get value, set checked flag or do whatever you need to
                  Answers.push(radios[i].value);
              }
          }

          console.log(Answers); // eg array with values selected ["halal_yes ", "vegi_no"]
      });
```

You can additionally simplify the condition statements so you are not repeating yourself :

```
  var ihtml = "<img src='img/poll.gif' width =' + wsize + height='20'> + wsize + '%'" ;

  var wsize = function(x) { // Where x = the variable no
      if(x){
            return 100 * Math.round( voteno / (voteno + voteyes );
      } else {
           return 100 * Math.round( voteyes / (voteno + voteyes );
      }
  }

  if(!hingID){
      document.getElementById("V1" + vingID).remove();
      document.getElementById("V" + vingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
      wsize(no);
  } else if(!vingID ){
      document.getElementById("H1"+hingID).remove();
      document.getElementById("H"+hingID).document.createElement("ihtml");
      wsize(no);
  }
```

The Poll answers are stored in an array `Answers` you can then send this to you server and process the information. For example, using AJAX ( You need Jquery)

```
   // Call this function instead of console.log in the above example
          $.ajax({
             method:"POST",
             url:"Answers.php", // path to your php file
             data: {data:Answers},
             success: function(){
                  // function to run when results are submitted
                 alert("Answers Submitted. Thank you..")
             },
             error: function(){
                // handle form submission errors here..
                 alert('There was an error processing your Poll. Try again..')
             }
          });
```

then in your `Answers.php` file try  to add `var_dump($_POST);` so you will be able to see the structure of the data being posted, in this case  :

```
  array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "halal_yes "
    [1]=>
    string(7) "vegi_no"
  }
}
  // $Halal = $data[0] ; 
 // $Vegi = $data[1] ;
```

Comment: how do i view the array, alert(array[2][0]) returns [

Comment: thanks for your in depth answer really appreciate your effort,  but in my case I need ingid as I need to keep in track of the vote by adding it back to the database and saving the ip . I manage to get it working by sending the specific elements from the array. Now im just trying the image thing and I am looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

try like this instead of

```
onclick="getVote(this.value)"
```

use

```
onclick="getVote(this)"
```

and in javascript try to get like below

```
 var val = item.value;
 var testsplit = val.split(" ");
```

Comment: $ not defined error though i think thats not an issue since the value display when doing alert(testsplit)

Comment: im having a problem retrieving/viewing the php array sent, how do i access an array within an array in javascript i tried testsplit[2][0]

Comment: i am sending 3 values value="vegi_yes '.$ingID." ".$vegiVote.'" 
where $vegiVote[0]=1; $vegiVote[1]=20; as an example, however the original value is derived from the result of the table