# How to use a constant for multiple images in img tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have images hosted in a server for which I have absolute paths.

Is there a way to use a constant for the base url part?

I mean I have:

```
<img src="someexample.com/someImage.jpg" ... />
<img src="someexample.com/someOtherImage.jpg" ... />
```

Instead I want to use something like:

```
<img src= someVariable + "/someImage.jpg" ... />
<img src= someVariable + "/someOtherImage.jpg" ... />
```

This way if I need to change the url I can just change the constant.

Comment: what have you tried? seems quiet easy with JS.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: @PhilippSander Not planning to do with JS. There are already hundreds of these used in the age old html. So was thinking if somehow this could be done within the html itself. If not, then I will change it with javascript.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee can be done if you are using php or angularjs or jsp :P

Comment: *if somehow this could be done within the html itself* No. HTML is a presentation language. You give markup, it will present it.

Comment: `HTML` is a mark up language what it does is show what ever you have marked to the user the way it has been marked. It's not a programming language (as some people tend to think). To get your purpose you need to use a scripting language.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee downvote is because you are trying to do something that the language is not meant for. HTML is **just** representational language. If you wish to add some programming things like concatination, you **will** have to use some scripting language. JS or PHP or anything else. But with plain old HTML, the answer is No, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<base href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>
<body>
<img src="stickman.gif" width="24" height="39" alt="Stickman">
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</body>
```

You can use base path. Example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: this will also affect links!

Comment: I only need to change the constant part of the link. Your answer does not provide that.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Well, pure HTML is not that flexible and this is the only way to do it. According to your comment you wanted to try with HTML only solution, now you can choose and decide whether you go with JS or not