# Javascript creating <img>

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that is creating  to div after clicking on button. But its not working... here is the html with script in it

```
<img id="boxm" style="position: fixed;left: 90%;padding-top:2%" 
src="images/box1.png" id="image1" onclick="diffImage(this);myFunction();" />
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("surprise").createElement="<img 
style="width:304px;height:228px"
src='images/mese.png' />";
}
</script>

<div id="surprise">

</div>
```

Comment: You have to escape double quote from img element.

Comment: `Document` has a `createElement` method, `Element` doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src='images/box1.png' onclick="showSurpriseImage()" />
<div id="surprise">
    Surprise Image will be displayed here
</div>
<script>
function showSurpriseImage() {
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "images/mese.png");
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("height", "228");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "surprise image");

    document.getElementById("surprise").appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Best Practice to set attributes [checkout here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, how would you do random TOP and LEFT position? I tried to do this     var randomY = Math.round(Math.random() * availH) + 'px';
                var randomX = Math.round(Math.random() * availW) + 'px';  
                x.style.left = randomX;
                x.style.top = randomY;

Comment: Code remain same. depends on the availH and availW before that do console the randomX and randomY check what it returns

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img id="boxm" 
src="http://wfarm1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set28/7f8535d7.png" id="image1" onclick="myFunction();" />
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var s = document.getElementById("surprise")
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "http://wfarm1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set28/7f8535d7.png");
    s.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

<div id="surprise">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("surprise").innerHTML='<img style="width:304px;height:228px" src="images/mese.png" />';
}
```