# Getting the img url, but not the img, what im i doing wrong? (Javascript, API and JSON)

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to js and started learning about API and JSON three weeks ago! Struggling to get an image from my function.

I have a js document , fetched api, converted to JSON and just wondering how I can get my image to show, right now i just get the img URL :-S

```
function myFunction(result){

    var createCard = result.cards;

    for (var i=0; i<createCard.length; i++){
      var card = document.createElement('article');
        var name1 = document.createElement('p');
        var id1 = document.createElement('p');
        var img1 = document.createElement('url');

        name1.textContent = createCard[i].name;
        id1.textContent = createCard[i].id;
        img1.textContent = createCard[i].imageUrl;

        card.appendChild(name1);
        card.appendChild(img1);
        card.appendChild(id1);

        div.appendChild(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an img element to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Comment: You might want to (a) learn some basic HTML and (b) think about what is implied by the property name *textContent*

Comment: `var img1 = document.createElement('url');` should probably be `var img1 = document.createElement('img');`; then you wouldn't set its `textContent` but rather its `src`

Comment: Why did you use [tag:api]? It says, right at the top, "DO NOT USE".

Comment: .. This is a school assignment, I was told to do it this way.. I have basic HTML understanding, Im just terrible at JS!  Im new to this, just signed up for some help, get tips and to get better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can do this

```
var oImg = document.createElement("img");
oImg.setAttribute('src', createCard[i].imageUrl);
oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'image');
```

Comment: That's **awful** alt text.

Comment: That is just for an example. It can be set as per user convienence