# Adding images into a <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a "Crystals Collector" game which creates four crystals ("divs") with random numbers inside them, which the user clicks to add numbers to a random number the computer has generated, to match the computer's random number. Everything works but I'm having a hard time adding the images of crystals I need into the 4 divs.

```
var image = "../../assets/images/crystal.jpg"

var crystal = $("<div>");
crystal.attr({
    "class": 'crystal',
    "data-random": randomNum,
    "src": image
});
$(".crystals").append(crystal);
```

The only result I need is for 4 crystal images to show in my 4 divs created for the random number clicks.

Comment: you need to create the `img` tag, set it's src to the image url and then append it to the `crystals`.

Comment: You're creating a `<div>`. Create an `img` instead: `var crystal = $("<img/>");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an img element to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Comment: Well, I need the 4 ```<divs>``` to store the random numbers within. Basically, I need 4 ```<divs>``` to store both random numbers AND images within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `div` create `img` tag.

```js
var image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"

var crystal = $("<img>");
crystal.attr({
    "class": 'crystal',
    "data-random": 1,
    "src": image,
    "height": '100px',
    "width": '100px'
});

$(".crystals").append(crystal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="crystals"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Create the image and add to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript)

> ```
> var elem = document.createElement("img");
> elem.setAttribute("src", "images/hydrangeas.jpg");
> elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
> elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
> elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
> document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
> ```