# How do I expose images from json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have looped over some json and have pulled urls from the data. The thumbnail data looks like:

```
{href: "https://link/medium.jpg"}
   href: "https://link/medium.jpg"
    >__proto__: Object
```

How can I expose each url so the actual images display on the browser not the links. This is my code. `console.log(o._links.thumbnail)` is the data I receive from above:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Fetch Json</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      thumbnail: 
    </p>
    <script>
      const url =
        "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example.json";
      async function getThumbnail() {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        var art = data._embedded.artworks;
        art.forEach(function(o) {
          //console.log(o._links.thumbnail);
          var img = document.createElement("image");
          img.src = o._links.thumbnail; //set the value equal to the href
          document.querySelector("body").appendChild(img);
    });
  }

  getThumbnail();
</script>
```

Comment: what is the _embedded.artworks? try to access data.href to access the image location

Comment: Try to use [<img />](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manipulate the DOM, something like this.

```
let elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.src = o._links.href;
document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
```

Reference:

[Adding an img element to a div with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802744/adding-an-img-element-to-a-div-with-javascript)

Comment: When I try that I don't actually see the image. I see a little icon that shows images are supposed to be placed there (and I receive a 404)

Comment: The src should be `o._links.thumbnail.href`

Answer (score 1):

Try to append `image` elements and set the `src` attribute to the value of `href`
this is more general than the code I posed before:

1) Loop thru your json
2) create image element

`var img = document.createElement("image");
 img.src = o._links.thumbnail; //set the value equal to the href
 document.querySelector("body").appendChild(img);`

Comment: When I try that I see <image src="[object Object]"><image src="[object Object]">...

Comment: Because the `image` element was not actually an element the last time. I fixed the code. Try now please

Comment: by the way, if you are getting object Object, it is because `o._links.thumbnail` is not actually referring to the the `href` value. That you may have to set according to the json structure you have there

Comment: I edited my code for you to check but it's not actually displaying anything now

Comment: `img.src = o._links.thumbnail; //set the value equal to the href`
As I said, it could be
`img.src = o._links.thumbnail.href;`